# Why does convert fill my fontconfig directory?

Tags: xorg, fontconfig

I want to have the time displayed a bunch of times in my linux background.

Here's a partial screenshot:[image: partial screenshot]

I use this script to make that happen:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

while true
do
    convert -size 400x80 xc:black -pointsize 24 -fill white -undercolor '#00000080' -gravity Center -annotate +0+8 "$(date)" output.jpg&& xloadimage -onroot output.jpg >& /dev/null
    sleep 1

done
```

The problem is that this generates a ton of files in my ~/.cache/fontconfig directory and eventually, I run out of inodes.

So, my question:

1. Is there a better way to plaster the current time all over my background?
2. Is there a way to get the convert command to not generate a file in the fontconfig cache?

Before asking this question, I thought about a cron that deletes these files each morning, but that's a stupid solution.

Hopefully, stupid measures are not required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not delete the file as part of the script?

Comment: @djsmiley2k You mean just delete the .cache/fontconfig dir from the script? The created files have names like: 7fedd887-d881-4cb6-9fa2-8a7ff7c1a8b9-le64.cache-7 I have no clue what these files are for.

Comment: Well, you're thinking about deleting them via a cronscript so I figured you knew they were safe to delete. It'd be good to know what's creating them first, but I'd try and be selective with your deleting also. `rm ~/.cache/fontconfig/*.cache-*` or such